# How to retrieve the max key and max value from a dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x

```
a = ['also', 'akin', 'akee','ague', 'aero', 'anes','here','beer','bute', 'byre', 'came', 'case', 'doze', 'down', 'drek', 'drew', 'dyes', 'fret', 'freo']
i = 'e'#i is user guess input
dic = {}
for item in a:
    key = ''
    for chr in item:
        if chr == i:
            key += i
        else:
            key += '-'
    if key not in dic:
        dic[key] = []
    dic[key].append(item)
print(dic)

c = max(k for k, v in dic.items())
d = max(v for k, v in dic.items())

print('\nmax key:',c)
print('\nmax value:',d)
```

Output:

```
{'---e': ['ague', 'bute', 'byre', 'came', 'case', 'doze'], '--ee': ['akee'], '----': ['also', 'akin', 'down'], '-e-e': ['here'], '-ee-': ['beer'], '--e-': ['anes', 'drek', 'drew', 'dyes', 'fret', 'freo'], '-e--': ['aero']}
max key: -ee-
max value: ['here']
```

In the above example, a is a list of words. When the user guess a letter, for example 'e', the program iterates through each word in the list. Replace any letter that is not 'e' to a dash '-'.

I tried to map that result into a dictionary to keep track of the each group of words that where letter 'e' occurs in the same position.

Now, i want to retrieve the group of words(or key) with the largest number of words. Judging by the output, i'm not doing that because key'-e--' has the largest number of words.

I've also tried

```
max(dic.keys())
max(dic)
dic.get(max(dic.keys()))
```

Am i not fully understand the concept of max key and values for a dictionary?

Please suggest how i can fix this.

Thanks

Comment: not very clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry, i made a mistake while posting the question.

Comment: that would be more like `max(dic.keys(), key=lambda x: len(dic[x]))` then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question, the notion of `max` means `being associated with the largest list.`, or `being the largest list`

```
max(dic.keys(), key=lambda x: len(dic[x]))
```

Will give you the maximum of dic's keys

Also,

```
sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda x:len(x[1]), reverse=True)
```

(in this example, `lambda (x, y): len(y)` works in python 2, not sure about python 3)

Will output a list of key, value tuples sorted by number of matches:

```
[('---e', ['ague', 'bute', 'byre', 'came', 'case', 'doze']), ('--e-', ['anes', 'drek', 'drew', 'dyes', 'fret', 'freo']), ('----', ['also', 'akin', 'down']), ('-e-e', ['here']), ('--ee', ['akee']), ('-e--', ['aero']), ('-ee-', ['beer'])]
```

### Edit, no lambda

Without using a lambda, you'd be using a regular function:

```
def myMax(value_tuple):
    key, value = value_tuple
    return len(value)
```

and using it like so:

```
max(dic.items(), key=myMax)
```

Comment: I'm an absolute programming amateur.  Can you please explain the usage of 'lambda'? I'm taking my first programming course, we haven't talked about 'lambda'.  Is there another way of achieving the goal without using lambda?

Comment: `lambda` is a way of declaring a very short function that only performs one statement that is its return value. You can use a regular function, I'll post an example

Comment: Thank you for the example, i actually understood how you defined the def myMax.

Answer (score 0):

- Retrieve max key:

  max(MyDictionary.keys(), key=type).
- Retrieve max value:

max(MyDictionary.values(), key=type)

Replace type with the key type in both cases. i.e int

Hope it helps.